# How can I see the contract code in Solana?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

On Ethereum, I can go to the Etherscan link for a contract address and view the code and Read/Write ABIs. I can't seem to find this on Solana Explorer, Solscan, or anything. What's the best way for me to see IDL signatures and/or the Rust code in the functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like on Ethereum, some programs are submitted and verified. This is done using the Anchor verification process.

An example can be found with the [Serum V3 program](https://explorer.solana.com/address/9xQeWvG816bUx9EPjHmaT23yvVM2ZWbrrpZb9PusVFin).

The `Anchor Verified` badge links to the actual source code of the program, where you can get the IDL, Anchor's version of ABI.

**Note**: Also like Ethereum, not all programs are verified. This feature is rather new, and still being adopted. I hope to see more programs use this feature in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response, super helpful. Does this mean though that there's no way I can tell in a readable way how to engage with the contract unless it is verified?

Comment: @EdwardSun Yes. You usually need some kind of contract or source in order to interact with it

Comment: Can you please share any  Anchor Verified NFT hash as I'm not able to find a particular badge?